# Augmentum broken in Lilypond Vaticana notation

Tags: lilypond

While transcribing Vexilla regis I came across a weird issue with augmenta being offset to the right.

```
\version "2.19.81"
\include "gregorian.ly"

cantus = \relative c' {
  \[ \augmentum g \melisma \flexa \augmentum f \melismaEnd \] \divisioMaior
  f \[ g( \pes a ) \]
}

cantusLyrics = \lyricmode { tor sus -- pen }

\score { \new VaticanaVoice = "cantus" \cantus \addlyrics \cantusLyrics }
```

[image]

The augmenta from the first ligature are almost hidden by the last ligature.

When I leave the last ligature off, the augmenta are rendered correctly: [image]

What's causing this and how can I fix it? Is there an error somewhere that I'm not seeing?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help, but I can confirm the same problem with LilyPond 2.18.2. I did have to use the following score block though: `\score {
  <<
    \new VaticanaVoice  <<
      \clef "vaticana-fa1" \music
    >>
  >>
}` This appears to be a similar problem to the one described in [this mailing list post](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/lilypond-user/2017-01/msg00270.html) and in [this thread](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/lilypond-user/2014-01/msg00849.html), with a possible workaround described.

Comment: @Greg Have you seen my response?

Comment: Some time passed since my response and I gained some experience. I have to say, that gregorio with LaTeX is so advanced now, that it is superior to lilypond Vaticana in my opinion. Furthermore most scores are available on gregobase.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem and did some research. It looks like that it appears only at a `divisio`.
In some archive of the [lilypond mailing list](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/lilypond-user/2014-01/msg00857.html), I found the solution.

If you add two `s8` notes here, each `augmentum` will be rendered correctly:

```
\relative c' {  \[ \augmentum g \melisma \flexa \augmentum f \melismaEnd \]%
     s8 s \divisioMaior f \[ g( \pes a ) \]
}
```